# Disable all SELECTs with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a post form with a first dropdown for choosing a category and a second for choosing a subcategory. The second one changes according to the first category that was chosen.

I have many dropdowns and I show the most correct one depending on the chosen category.

I need to disable all dropdowns and enable that one so that I can submit the form correctly.

```
<select name='dropdown'></select>
<select name='dropdown'></select>
<select name='dropdown' id='1'></select>
```

How can I disable all selects with `name = 'dropdown'` except the one with id='1'?

Comment: numeric id's can be apart of html5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @ankur20us - just because you *can* use them, doesn't mean you should. Numeric IDs are a very bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('select.dropdown').attr('disabled', true);
$('select#1').attr('disabled',false);
```

Comment: sorry the question was not correct. I need to enable '#1' not ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select.dropdown').prop('disabled', true);
$('select.dropdown#1').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: sorry the question was not correct. I need to enable '#1' after disabling all not ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Please, Use below jquery line.

```
$('select:not("#1")').attr('disabled', true);​​​
```

jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/n9af3/)

For more information visit [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).